# Date conversion in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, date-conversion

I need some help as I am not an experience programmer.  I looked through the records, but couldn't find answer.

I have an application which will allow me to add variables (I believe it's liquid).  For example, I can add first name %{first_name}, Last Name %{last_name}, Date Created %{date_created}, among other things. The date is something that comes over like mm/dd/yyyy.  I would like to be able to change the format of the date to dd.mm.yyyy.

Here's an example of the code.  I made it more simple:

```
<body>
<p>Hello %{first_name} %{last_name}, thank you for your service.  You were enrolled in %{date_created} 
</body>
```

The output is:
Hello John Smith, thank you for your service.  You were enrolled in 07/09/2016

I need the date to be 09.07.2016

I believe I should use some javascript or maybe jquery, but I'm not too familiar with it. I'm using a proprietary CMS that has a WYSIWYG.

Comment: See [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Suggest you modify/extend the cms code or configuration setup. Otherwise you need to use regular expression to first find if there is even a date in the text

Answer (score 0):

I have just written a simple function to return your date format but It can consider as hard-coded.

```js
function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
  month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;//Add 0 if month.length <= 1
  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;//Add 0 if day.length <= 1
  return day + '.' + month + '.' + year;
}
 
getFormattedDate(new Date('07/09/2016'));//It will return "09.07.2016"
```